# How do I construct a sql in GO MYSQL with many similar parameters?

Tags: mysql, go

I am currently using [GO MySQL](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) and I have a case where the sql contains many similar parameter.

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare(`
    SELECT id
    FROM questions
    WHERE description like '%?%'
    UNION
    SELECT id
    FROM books
    WHERE description like '%?%'
    UNION
    SELECT id
    FROM sites
    WHERE description like '%?%'`)

param := "golang"
stmt.Query(param, param, param)
```

My real life sql has about 10 similar parameters of `golang` and a 2nd parameter that repeats itself a few times. Is the positional parameter the only way to construct the sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the spread operator:

```
args := make([]string, 0)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    args = append(args, "param")
}

q.Query(args...)
```

More lines of code, but at least you don't have to Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V all the time.